# @ViewChild fails to deliver an ElementRef, can figure out why?

Tags: angular

I am trying to access an elementRef, but something fails,
I know about the issues that if there is some rending condition(*ngif) which is false, and the view is non existent, then you can't get the elementRef, that's true for when  the application is launched, but I try to access it much later, after its already been drawn.

html:

```
<div (click)="activateGroupDropdown()" class="group-name"><div class="title">Choose Site<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div #groupDropdown class="dropdown" [ngClass]="{'active': isGroupDropDown}">
        <ul [ngClass]="{'active': isGroupDropDown}">
            <li>Sparta</li>
            <li>Athene</li>
            <li >Vilnius</li>
            <li #liButtons class="action-btns">
                <button>cancel</button><button class="success">ok</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

ts:

```
export class CameraScreensOptionsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    @ViewChild('groupDropdown') elGroupDropdown: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('liButtons') elLastListItem: ElementRef;
    afterDropdownTransition(event) {
        console.log('transition ended!');
        if ( !this.isGroupDropDown ) {
             console.log('here!', this.elGroupDropdown );
             this.elGroupDropdown.nativeElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
    activateGroupDropdown() {
        this.isGroupDropDown = !this.isGroupDropDown;
        console.log('toggling the site grouping drop down');
    }
    initGrouping() {
        this.isGroupingInitiated = true;
       // moving the action to the end of the queue
       // so that angular would have time to draw view
       // before I put event listener on elLastListItem
       setTimeout( _ => this.elLastListItem.nativeElement.addEventListener('transitionend', this.afterDropdownTransition), 0);
       console.log('initiating grouping options display');
   }   
}
```

Comment: Where is `afterDropdownTransition` called? And when?

Comment: when `isGroupDropDown` changed, it changes the classes causing an transition, and its called on `transitionend` of that change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be more attentive when working with `addEventListener`:

```
.addEventListener('transitionend', this.afterDropdownTransition)
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    you will lose the context here
```

Quick fix is adding `.bind(this)`

```
.addEventListener('transitionend', this.afterDropdownTransition.bind(this))
```

The preceding code helps us to retain `this` within `afterDropdownTransition` function. It will refer to the component instance.

For other solutions see

- [value undefined in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445201/value-undefined-in-angular2/42445241#42445241)

Comment: Thank you, would've never found that out on my own!