# property navigate of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

AppService

```js
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, 
              private router: Router
              ) { }

user(): Observable<any> {
   return this.httpClient.get<any>('/users/details')
     .pipe(
       catchError(this.handleError)
     );
}


private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse){
    console.log('handleError' , error);
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side error....
    } else {
      // The backend error...
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}` +
        `  ${error.message}`
      );

      this.router.navigate(['/errors']);//READ HERE!!!!!
    }
    
  }
```

app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AppService, 
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: XhrInterceptor, multi: true } 
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

A possible problem could it be `this` is referring to the **wrong context**?

Comment: Have you imported the RouterModule into your module?

Comment: yes ... `import { Router } from '@angular/router';`

Comment: You are not trying to provide the router anywhere are you?

Comment: When I say imports I mean in your modules import section. @NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule

Comment: I have added my app.module.ts above.... thanks for taking the time

Comment: I would try `catchError(this.handleError).bind(this)`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445201/value-undefined-in-angular2/42445241#42445241

Comment: Thans but it didn't work...

Comment: can you show the router file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caller to `handleError` is an `Observable`, the context is not your controller instance. You need to change the *caller* to maintain context or bind the context:

Method 1:

```
catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))
```

Method 2:

```
catchError((err, caught) => this.handleError(err))
```

Comment: Thanks so much method 1 works.  Method 2 gave me this error `Argument of type '() => (error: HttpErrorResponse) => Observable<never>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<any>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow Function as part of ES6.

```
user(): Observable<any> {
   return this.httpClient.get<any>('/users/details')
     .pipe(
       catchError(() => this.handleError())
     );
}


private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse){
    console.log('handleError' , error);
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side error....
    } else {
      // The backend error...
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}` +
        `  ${error.message}`
      );

      this.router.navigate(['/errors']);
    }

  }
```

Comment: You forgot to call `this.handleError`

Answer (score 0):

To check whether your context is correct, and to check whether the `router` variable is provided to your component try printing `this`.

`console.log(this)`

It will print something similar to

`MyComponent {..., router: Router, ...}` if the router is provided to the component